# Stopping systemd unit together with another. Starting works

Tags: systemd

On a CentOS7 server I have an application stack composed by a Tomcat web server and a MySQL DB server, both installed on the same VM. 
I would like them to start and stop together in this order:

```
START: MySQL--> Tomcat
STOP: Tomcat-->MySQL
```

Reading systemd unit documentation, I managed to get them start together with `Requires=` directive, but when I stop tomcat with systemctl stop tomcat.service, MySQL keeps on running. On system logs I noticed that it does not even try to stop MySQL, so there must be something wrong with the systemd unit.

Here is my unit:

```
# Systemd unit file for tomcat
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=syslog.target network.target mysql.service
Requires=mysql.service

[Service]
Type=forking

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Hunch is that you should add a Before to the mysql.service

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What you are seeing here is the expected systemd behavior. The `Requires=` dependency will make sure `mysql.service` is started whenever `tomcat.service` starts, but once started the two units are independent and one won't be stopped when the other is.

If you really want `mysql.service` to be stopped when `tomcat.service` is, you can use the [`PartOf=` directive](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#PartOf=) which links units on stop and restart.

For the example you described (having `mysql.service` stop whenever `tomcat.service` is stopped), what you need is to add `PartOf=tomcat.service` to the definition of `mysql.service`. Usually, the best way to do so is to use an override file, which you can do with `systemctl edit mysql.service` which will open a text editor with an empty file, then you can add this snippet to it:

```
[Unit]
PartOf=tomcat.service
```

This will get saved in a file `/etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/override.conf` which becomes part of `mysql.service`, you can check that with `systemctl cat mysql.service`.

After those changes and a `systemctl daemon-reload`, this should work as you expect...

Regarding ordering, everything should work as you expect with the single `After=mysql.service` you have in `tomcat.service`, since the dependencies are respected in the reverse order when stopping services. (Which means, in this case, `tomcat.service` will be stopped first, followed by `mysql.service`.)

---

Stopping units this way might not be always a good idea... Perhaps a slightly better approach is to create a separate [`.target` unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.target.html) to group all services you want to control together. Perhaps something like `webservices.target`.

You would create that unit with contents such as:

```
[Unit]
Description=Web Services
Requires=tomcat.service mysql.service
After=tomcat.target mysql.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And then have both `tomcat.service` and `mysql.service` set a `PartOf=webservices.target`, using the override mechanism described above.

Enable the target unit with `systemctl enable webservices.target`, and then you can start and stop both services together with `systemctl start webservices.target` or `systemctl stop webservices.target`.

Comment: This is mostly from memory... If this still doesn't work for you, or if something is unclear, please let me know, I can follow up here to help you figure this out.

Comment: Worked very good creating a `webservices.target` as you suggested. Discovered also the existence of `systemctl edit ...` Thank you!