# How to make a systemd-timer depend on internet connectivity?

Tags: systemd, network-interface, services, systemd-timer, connectivity

I'm using `systemd-timer` to periodically run a script which consumes a webservice.
Problem is, upon system resume or wake-up, internet connectivity would not get started right away but the timer gets fired and hence the script returns error (If the service waits for a couple of seconds, the script would run correctly and there would be no need to postpone the task until next run.)

1- How can I make it so that the timer (or the service associated with it), waits until net connectivity is available?

2- How can I make the timer (or service) not call the script when system is not online yet?

Comment: How about just adding something like `sleep 5` at the top of your script? Might not be a solution, but with appropriate choice of sleep time should do as a workaround.

Comment: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add `After=network-online.target` to the `[Unit]` section of the timer.

**Explanation:**

Timers do accept all the relative ordering commands in the `[Unit]` section that are known for services. In fact both the `[Unit]` and `[Install]` sections are identical for timers and services. Form [the official manuals](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html):

> A unit configuration file whose name ends in ".timer" encodes information about a timer controlled and supervised by systemd, for timer-based activation.
>
> This man page lists the configuration options specific to this unit type. See [systemd.unit(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#) for the common options of all unit configuration files. The common configuration items are configured in the generic [Unit] and [Install] sections. The timer specific configuration options are configured in the [Timer] section.

That said you need to know about [network-online.target](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/) that defines if a network is **up**.

> network-online.target is a target that actively waits until the nework is "up", where the definition of "up" is defined by the network management software. Usually it indicates a configured, routable IP address of some kind. Its primary purpose is to actively delay activation of services until the network is set up.

**Limitations**

`network-online.target` is not checking for *internet* but for *network* connections. The LAN of course might not have internet access per se. If you cannot rely on the router or your ISP to provide a connection, you would have to make e.g. a special `test-internet.service` that pings some website and only is defined active after it succeeded once (and otherwise restarts on failure every 15s or so). That should be a `Type=oneshot` and `RemainAfterExit=yes` kind of service. But I assume that this is not what you asked for.

**Scopes: system/user**

Be careful, as `network-online.target` is a *system* scope unit.
Units in the *user* scope will not see it and fail to start. This can be fixed by creating a linked unit: `systemctl --user link /lib/systemd/system/network-online.target`. The path can vary, the location can be checked by running: `systemctl show --property FragmentPath network-online.target`

Comment: Thanks, do I also need to add `Wants=network-online.target`?

Comment: `Wants` will also make the timer try to start the network target. You may add it, but I think for your case it is not that necessary - since I assume you always start the network by default. If your connection is unstable, you may rather think of something like `BindsTo=`, i.e. stopping the timer if the network connection breaks. More details on the relative dependency options here: [Service unit configuration](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#)

Comment: and what would be the difference if I add `After=network-online.target` to the Unit section of corresponding `.service` file (not `.timer`)?

Comment: Simple: If you do not define to start the timer after online target, the countdown will start earlier (e.g. when you defined it as `WantedBy=multi-user.target` in the `[Install]` section it will start at boot time - independently of the network status). If you define it in the service file, it will wait for the online target after triggering the service via the timer.

Comment: `BindsTo=` option is only relevant in boot process? I mean, can I use it to disable the timer when network suddenly turns off and re-enable it when it becomes available? (After boot). I used `BindsTo=` and `After=` with `network-online.target` but when network came back online, the timer didn't reactivate

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator That is an emergeny stop only. Check the `PartOf=` directive for a start-and-stop dependency. More details [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440215)

Comment: Sorry for bothering again...actually my timer/service are defined in `.config/systemd/user` (user-level)...so I can't depend on `network-online.target` which is a system service, right?

I need to write my own `connection-detector` service at user-level right?

Comment: No worries. - Yes, system level and user level are fully independent - see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/147904) or [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/149959). I'd suggest you make a small ping test service to some reliable internet address.